# What's a idiom/colloquial phrase similar to "having skeletons in your closet"

Tags: phrase-requests, idioms, synonyms

I'm looking for phrase similar to that but it meant that you were hiding something bad unlike the skeleton one.

I totally forgot what phrase I linked to it :/

Comment: Skeletons ***are*** bad.

Comment: "unsharable secrets," "cover-up"

Comment: Like Jim alluded to, having skeletons in your closet ***actually means*** hiding something bad. No buts about it.

Answer (score 2):

***Dirty linen*** (or *dirty laundry*) works similarly.

TFD(idioms):

> **[dirty linen](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dirty+linen)**
>
> One's personal, intimate, or private matters or secrets, especially
>   that which may be embarrassing if made public.
>   From the expression
>   "don't wash/air your dirty linen in public." 
>   Those who consider
>   running for public office must be aware that their dirty linen is
>   likely to be exposed to the public. 
>   David is such a gossip, always
>   talking about other people's dirty linen.
>
> Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. © 2015 Farlex, Inc, all rights